# How to retrieve images from folder and store it with HttpRequest JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a folder `images`, where are my images in JPEG-Format.
I would like to retrieve all images from there and store them in an array, because later I want to build an slide-show with them.

So, my question is - how could I get and store my images?
I guess, I need to use HttpRequest, but I do not know how, I am really beginner...Could you please give me some advices?
So, for now I have this code

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
req.open('GET', './images')

req.onreadystatechange = function() { 
if (req.readyState === 4) { 
    var img = req.response;  
    // do I havte to loop here or retrieve img one by one?
}}
```

And here is structure of the project
[image: Structure]

PS. It is important for me not to write with jQuery, but with JS

Comment: Where is the page hosted?

Comment: @Teemu I add a screenshot to my question to show the structure

Comment: But the host? A local page, web-server hosted, nodejs ..? As it is, it shouldn't work in any host though, you can't get a folder from XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Teemu it's a local page...what should I use instead of XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: On a local page (if you want to  do this with pure JS) the only way is to use `input type="file"`, and let user to select the files manually. Alternatively you can hardcode the filelist into JS, but be aware, that XMLHttpRequest doesn't work with file protocol in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manipulate files in javascript on the browser. If you want to show images in your web you need to build dynamicaly a set of `<img ...>` tags with their `src` properties pointing to where your images are. You can achieve this  by asking with XMLHttpRequest asking the URLs of all the images you need to show and then build `<img ...>` using this URLs.

If you want to save Images from the users in you server you need to use an 
`<input type=file ...>` inside a form block, so you can send it later to your server

Comment: OP has a local page, i.e. a page working with file protocol. Explanations of how web pages are working are not an answer to the question.